# Cast string to long in kdb

Tags: list, casting, kdb

I want to first break a string to list of strings and based on a condition I want to return an item of a list as long.

```
Func:{[x]
  Temp:vs "-" x;
  if["AAA" ~  Temp[0];:"J"$Temp[1];:"J"$Temp[2]]
 }

 Func["AAA-809-AXSDF"]
```

This function returns 809 but when I do:

```
 809 ~ Func["AAA-809-AXSDF"]
```

It returns `0b`

This means it's not converting list item to long. Please suggest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few errors in your code:

1: `[x]` is not necessary

2: `vs "-" x` should be `"-" vs x`

3: `if["AAA" ~  Temp[0];:"J"$Temp[1];:"J"$Temp[2]]` this statement if true **always returns** `:"J"$Temp[1]`, `:"J"$Temp[2]` will never be executed. I think what you need is the conditional `$` operator

```
q)func:{"J"$ $["AAA"~first a:"-"vs x;a 1;a 2]}
q)809~func["AAA-809-AXSDF"]
1b
q)111~func["AAB-AXSDF-111"]
1b
```

Answer (score 1):

If I got the logic right, following code solves the issue:

```
{x: "-"vs x; "J"$ $["AAA"~x 0;x 1; x 2]}"AAA-809-AXSDF"
```